# Updating SQL rows where row matches user log in ID

Tags: php, sql, updating

I have a problem with this line of code - I have spent most of the day trying to get this resolved - can any one help?
Here is the code that is causing the problem form what I can see! The problem is around the $qry...

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO members (employer, flat) VALUES('$employ','$address') WHERE     login='$_login'";
    $result = @mysql_query($qry);
    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        header("location: member-profile.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

ERROR showing is:
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: _login in C:\wamp\www\123456\update.php on line 67

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

First variable `$_login` is Undefined, and second, it seems you are trying to update. 
You do not user `WHERE` for `SELECT` query.

If you want to update, it then your query should very much like this:

`$sql = 'UPDATE table SET username = '$username' WHERE id = $_login;`

variable $_login means, pretty much, the variable `$_login` is not defined. You must give it a value, before you can you expect it to work in  your query.

Answer (score 0):

[`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) doesn't allow the `WHERE` attribute, you need to use [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html) instead

```
"UPDATE members SET employer='$employ', flat='$address' WHERE login='$_login'"
```

Be sure to prevent SQL injections and since `mysql_*` functions are deprecated you should switch to MySQLi or PDO

As for the error itself, you need to check if the variables are defined that you are using

```
if (!isSet($_login))
    // do sth
```

Comment: It does if you are inserting from another datasource, table/view etc.